# How can I use python3.10 with brew on mac?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, symlink, python-3.10

I installed python3.10 by using `brew install python@3.10` But here's what happened.

```
$python3.10
zsh : command not found : python3.10

$which python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.9

$ls -al /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 host  admin  39 Mar 30 12:17 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 host  admin  46 Mar 30 12:17 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 host  admin  41 Mar 30 12:17 /usr/local/bin/python3.9 -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 host  admin  48 Mar 30 12:17 /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config -> ../Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12/bin/python3.9-config

$ls /usr/local/Cellar/python*
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10:
3.10.2

/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9:
3.9.12
```

So it seems like there is a python3.10 installed on Cellar but there's no symlink in /usr/local/bin for it. When I installed python3.9, I didn't have to setup those things. How can I add&use python3.10? Creating symlink on my own to /usr/local/bin is the last thing I want to do. I hope there's some command for brew to make this done.

Comment: what's the output of `which python` and `which python3`?

Comment: `python : aliased to python3.9` `python3 : aliased to python3.10` seems like both aliased to python3.10.

Answer (score 9):

When you have a previous version of Python installed, brew won't link the new version by default.

To fix this, run `brew link --overwrite python@3.10`

You can also do a dry-run of this first:

```
brew link python@3.10
```

You may need to add the `--overwrite` flag if you have previously linked versions of python

```
brew link --overwrite python@3.10
```

You can test the commands by adding the `--dry-run` flag.

```
$ brew link --dry-run python@3.10
Would link:
/usr/local/bin/2to3
#...
/usr/local/bin/python3.10
#...
```

When `/usr/local/bin/python3.10` is linked, you can then use `python3.10` to invoke that version of python.